# Странный ответ от сервера

Tags: java, сокет, tcp

клиент на Java.
Делаю запрос на сервер через TCP и считываю ответ в массв байтов byte[]. Он приходит в странном виде. Байты чередуются [байт ответа, '\u0000', байт ответа, '\u0000' ...]
Аналогичный php код принимает ответ корректно. 
Даже ошибки выдает в таком виде:

```
T a k e   t o o   l o n g   t o   l o g   i n
```

Почему такой ответ получается?

---

```
class SampleClient{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        String host = "91.121.133.113";
        int port =25565;

        Socket s = new Socket(host, port);

        byte b1 =(byte) 0xfe01;
        byte b2 =(byte) 0xfd;
        byte b3 =(byte) (9);
        byte b4 =(byte) 73;
        byte b5 =(byte) port;
        byte [] bytes = {b1,b2,b3,b4,b5};

        s.getOutputStream().write(bytes);

        // читаем ответ
        byte buf[] = new byte[2*1024];
        int r = s.getInputStream().read(buf);
        String data = new String(buf, 0, r);

        System.out.println("Исходная строка: "+ new String (buf));
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("init error: "+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Может стоит спросить сервер?

Comment: аналогичный код в php нормально выводит ответ

Comment: В таком случае, наверное, стоит добавить в стартовый пост конкретики по поводу получения ответа от сервера.

Comment: может быть такое, что сервер отвечает 16 битами, а я читаю по 8?

Comment: В данной ситуации может быть все что угодно, так как конкретики (кода) Вы пока не дали.

Comment: У вас ответ в какой кодировке приходит? Может надо её указать, при переводе в строку. Например: `String data = new String(buf, "UTF-8")`

Comment: не знаю в какой кодировке приходит ответ. Но Ваше предложение ничего не изменило.

Comment: Сохраните ответ сервера в файл и откройте его в хекс редакторе.

Comment: безрезультатно. Все то же самое. Вот только когда в np++ выбрал "преобразовать в Ascii" строка приняла верный вид. Как подобное сделать программно в Java?